# Time complexity of this mergesort algorithm for linkedlists

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

I've run this algorithm and I know that it works but I'm not too sure about its worst case time complexity.
I think that the worst case time complexity for this mergesort algorithm is O(n log n). I would be thankful for anyone that can provide a second opinion.

```
//The main function 
public Node mergeSort(Node a){
    Node oldHead = a;
    int mid = length(a)/2;

    if(a == null || a.next == null)
        return a;

    while(mid-1 > 0){
        oldHead = oldHead.next;
        mid--;
    }
    Node newHead = oldHead.next;

    oldHead.next = null;
    oldHead = a;

    Node t1 = mergeSort(oldHead);
    Node t2 = mergeSort(newHead);

    return merge(t1,t2);
}


public Node merge(Node a, Node b){
    Node result = head;

    if(a == null)
        return b;

    if(b == null)
        return a;

    if(b.name.compareTo(a.name) <= 0){
        result = b;
        result.next = merge(a,b.next);
    }
    else{
        result = a;
        result.next = merge(a.next,b);
    }           
    return result;
}


public int length(Node a){
    int count = 0;
    Node c = a;
    while( c != null){
        count++;
        c = c.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You should really change the merge step to an iterative version (instead of the recursion) or you risk a stack overflow for longer lists.

Comment: Note - it would be faster to use a [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists), which uses a small (25 to 32) fixed size array of pointers to internal lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is still O(n log(n)). Nothing is changed here from the traditional Merge sort algorithm to alter it's time complexity. The only real difference with linked lists is splitting the list in two. This has complexity of O(n) but it is at the same level as the merge operation which also has complexity O(n). So it has no overall effect on the complexity.

edit. The length operation is O(n) but again it is at the same level as the split operation and the merge operation, which are also O(n) so it too doesn't effect the time complexity.